# Can I declare the same multiple abstract methods with different parameters?

Tags: php, abstract-class, optional-parameters

Can I somehow do this in an abstract class in php:

```
    abstract function AddFilter();

    abstract function AddFilter( /*array*/ $c_array='', /*string*/ $url='')

    // ... etc...
```

using optional parameters / how do I do this?
if i just use the second one i get 'Declaration ofContent::AddFilter() must be compatible with that of ContentGeneric::AddFilter() '

**update**: ok... my method is now to add a single line callback function in the extended  AddFilter() which works but is ofcourse not the nicest, whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. PHP does not support overloading functions with different signatures like e.g. C++ does. If you want to emulate something like this, take a look at the [__call() magic method](http://nl.php.net/__call).